# Tableau performance with 500 concurrent users

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, tableau-api, bigdata

We are planning to use Tableau server with 8 core machine and 64 GB RAM for Data visualization as it has many rich features. Our idea is to use Spark SQL with hive metadata as the data input and mostly Live queries on top of it.

**Can anyone who used the same architecture provide their thoughts on how tableau will behave with more than 500 concurrent users**

Comment: Tableau has multiple white papers you should refer to, let alone their own support staff. You haven't even asked a question - just expressed a concern.

Comment: Tableau released a load test generator to github called TabJolt that you can use to test and tune your server configuration before rolling it out, along with server monitor and log file analyzes to help with tuning.